# How to share a file using flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am wondering how to share a file in a flutter app?

I saw some old references to using Intents with mojo, but that no longer seems to be present.  This seems like a standard feature that we should be able to handle in a cross-platform way (obviously with some differences between ios to android).

What is the current best practices for sharing files (e.g. via email)? The closest thing I could fine is UrlLauncher, which I could imagine using to launch a handler for a file that I want shared, but it seems a stretch.

Comment: Thanks for asking! We're tracking this at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7111

Comment: That issue has now been closed, but only with support for sharing a string. This new issue requests file transfers: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16743.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For anybody still finding this question, you can now share something with the share plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share

Edit: This plugin only supports text/link share which is not sufficient for directly sharing files. The issues https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16743 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19607 track file sharing directly in flutter.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP asked specifically about sharing a file, whereas this plugin supports sharing text only.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [EsysFlutterShare Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share). In version 1.0.0 you can share any file you like and its working on both, iOS and Android.

Just put that in yout pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  esys_flutter_share: ^1.0.0
```

Import the lib:

```
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
```

Share a file:

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png');
```

You need to privide a title, a file name, the file-bytes and a mime type.

Comment: does it work only with files in assets? How can I share a picture I have in Downloads for example?

Comment: Hi @LeonardoRignanese do you have solution to share downloaded file to share ? Thank you...

Comment: Note that the most recent (and final?) version of the _esys_flutter_share_ plugin (1.0.2) [doesn't work on iPadOS](https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/issues/46).

Answer (score 11):

I used [share_extend](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share_extend) combined with **path_provider** to share an audio file and it works perfectly.

```js
void share() async {
  Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File testFile = new File("${dir.path}/sound.m4a");
  if (!await testFile.exists()) {
    await testFile.create(recursive: true);
    testFile.writeAsStringSync("test for share documents file");
  }
  ShareExtend.share(testFile.path, "file");
}
```

Comment: when i use this i am getting this exception:  E/flutter (11283): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel com.zt.shareextend/share_extend)
E/flutter (11283): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7

Comment: Try adding this to your android manifest file

`
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works like a charm!

Comment: set minimum_sdk_version  to 19 and its works

Comment: Do anyone know how to send a list of files in share_extends

Comment: This will break with Web FYI.

Answer (score 7):

Flutter just accepted a long time PR, the [Share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/share) can now also share files!

ex:

```
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image.jpg'], text: 'Great picture');
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/image1.jpg', '${directory.path}/image2.jpg']);
```

Comment: how can I share pdf file using this package

Comment: instead of using the ".jpg" in the examples I listed, use the name of your pdf + ".pdf" on the end of it

`Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/yourPdf.pdf'], text: 'Your PDF!');`

Comment: `directory.path` of WHAT? please provide full code.

Comment: I'm sure you've figured this out by now but if you have a `File`, replace `'${directory.path}/yourPdf.pdf'` in that example with `file.path`.

Comment: `shareFiles` method is now deprecated, use `shareXFiles` now. 
by example: `await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(yourPath)]);`.

Comment: @busuu from path_provider. by example: `final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();`. :)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking to ***reverse share*** or in other words, **have other apps share data to your flutter app**, have a look at https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter .

Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer on the flutter Gitter channel!

This was the closest question I found to 'sharing' something to a flutter app and there doesn't seem to be a SO question for this particular usecase, hence this answer here

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no built-in way to do this.  As Seth Ladd mentioned above, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7111 is tracking making this easier.

For now, you would have to write the necessary share code in Objective-C or Java and call it from your Dart using the platform-services model documented at https://flutter.io/platform-services and shown in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/hello_services.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this reply, since the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question.

using [flutter-share from this github repo](https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share.git) you can share files by just adding it as dependency, import it, and then instantiate the Share class with the named constructor file like so: `Share.file(path: <String>, mimeType: ShareType, title: , text: );` where mimeType, title and text are optional, and then call share on it.

It is fully functional for Android, the IOS part is currently being developed to match the Android part (only having plainText share at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

Now, the best way is to use [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus/example) package

```
List<String> paths = [filePath];
await Share.shareFiles(
  paths,
  subject: 'subj',
  text: 'text',
);
```

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon it is maintaining, last update was 2 days ago..